# why does bin(byte) not work in python, but this works?

Tags: python, binary, byte

Using the python 3.8 console

```
sum(bin(byte).count("1") for byte in bytes([111]))
```

retuns 6 but

```
sum(bin(bytes([111])).count("1"))
```

gives

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

how can i display the binary representation of a byte?

Comment: because in the first one, you iterate on bytes, (which gives integers) and the second one you don't. Also, you seem to have mixed up `binary` and `bytes` maybe? what does `how can i display the binary representation of a byte?` mean?

Comment: thank you for the answer, i would like to iterate through the bits of a given byte

Comment: It seems like you just want `bin(111).count("1")`. `bin(111)` is the string: `'0b1101111'`

Comment: Yeah i want something like "0b1101111". but what do i do if i have given a byte instead of a int?